# Do we have classification (upto Morita equivalence) of Lie groupoids?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groupoids

Vague question is the following:

> Is there a classifcation of Lie groupoids?

Slightly less vague question is the following:

> Is there a (short?) list of "types" of Lie groupoids such that any arbitrary Lie groupoid is Morita equivalent to one from the list?

Some Lie groupoids I know are the following:

1. Lie groupoids coming from manifolds $[M\rightrightarrows M]$,
2. Lie groupoids coming from Lie group $[G\rightrightarrows *]$,
3. Lie groupoids coming from action of a Lie group on a manifold $[G\times M\rightrightarrows M]$,
4. Lie groupoids coming from foliation on a manifold $\mathcal{F}(M)$,
5. Lie groupoids coming from a submersion, the submersion groupoid $[M\times_NM\rightrightarrows M]$
6. Lie groupoids coming from a principal $G$-bundle, the Gauge groupoid,
7. Lie groupoids coming from a vector bundle over $M$, the general linear Lie groupoid $[GL(E)\rightrightarrows M]$.

Do we know any "interesting" Lie groupoids that do not belong (not Morita equivalent) to the above list?

Only classification I know is if a Lie groupoid is proper and étale, then it is locally looks like action Lie groupoid.

I might have forgot one or two types, but these are the only types of Lie groupoids I have come across till now.

**Edit**: It turns out my question was not conveyed correctly. I do know that there is no hope of classifying Lie groups. I do not want to classify Lie groups. For me, all Lie groupoids that comes from Lie groups are of "same type". So, the classification I am looking for is only based on types. I think I conveyed it correctly now. If this is not clear, please do ask for more clarification.

Comment: Lie groups sit inside Lie groupoids via the delooping construction, and there is no hope of classifying Lie groups.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov It looks like I have not mentioned it clearly.. Yes, I do know that there is no hope of classifying Lie groups... I do not want to classify Lie groups :D For me Lie groupoids coming from Lie groups are of "same type"... Does it now make it clear what I was trying to understand?

Comment: What is a “type” of a Lie groupoid?  Your list of 7 items looks like a fairly ordinary list of examples of Lie groupoids that one would give in a typical expository text after a definition.  Clearly, there are many more examples, and I do not understand why one would expect to exhaust all Lie groupoids by adding other examples to this list.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov "type" of a Lie groupoid is not a standard terminology, I just invented now... I call Lie groupoids coming from Lie groups as one type.. Lie groupoids coming from manifolds as one type.. Lie groupoids coming from foliations as one type and so on...  Let me rephrase this in another way. Are there any "interesting" examples of Lie groupoids which are not Morita equivalent to any of the above 7 types? Here, interesting does not have a unique meaning and I leave it to you to interpret in a fair manner :)

Comment: So it appears that the actual question being asked here is “What are some interesting examples or constructions of Lie groupoids?”.  This is _radically_ different from classifying Lie groupoids in any sense, since a typical example of a classification in this area is the Cartan–Killing classification of simple Lie group, a precise and complete result.  This newly revealed question, on the other hand, is clearly open-ended and does not have (or allow for) a complete answer.

Comment: You don't need étaleness to get locally like an action groupoid: proper is enough.

Comment: Given an appropriate Čech cocycle, one can construct a bundle gerbe from it à la Hitchin–Chatterjee. It will look like none of these, in general.

Comment: @DavidRoberts "It will look like none of these, in general".. not even locally? Moerdijk assumes the Lie groupoid is proper and etale to say it is locally an action Lie groupoid.. I saw this in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203100 (page 8).. May be it is true with out etale assumption..

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I am not asking for interesting examples or constructions of Lie groupoids.. I do not know why it is conveying in that way :O I do not know what other term to use other than classification for what I have mentioned before... Let me rephrase it again... I take all proper etale Lie groupoids to be of "same type" as all of them are locally action Lie groupoids...

Comment: Well, up to Morita equivalence, every proper Lie groupoid is glued together out of orthogonal actions of compact Lie groups on open unit balls. You don't need étaleness. I was thinking of gerbes not up to stable iso/Morita equivalence, so I guess I take that one back. Every U(1)-gerbe is, up to stable iso, the pullback of the universal gerbe which can be written down as a lifting gerbe (which looks like a proper action of an infinite-dimensional Lie group).

Comment: @DavidRoberts oh, ok. Do you think the question is not well phrased? If anything is not clear, I would like to make it clearer..

Comment: I don't know. The gauge groupoid one can be replaced by the same construction for an arbitrary fibre bundle, and there is the fundamental groupoid of a manifold (also has a Lie groupoid structure), but I think this might be covered by the foliation groupoid example, I can't remember precisely. I mean, all of the examples you give are essentially functorial constructions of Lie groupoids from other data. But who knows what an arbitrary Lie groupoid looks like? There is also the example of bundles of Lie groups, that's not on your list. Really you can only ask for more examples...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: It appears that I am not alone in being confused as to the actual meaning of your question; David Roberts voiced similar concerns.  Maybe you could give us some existing example of “classification into types” that you find acceptable.

Comment: @DavidRoberts  "But who knows what an arbitrary Lie groupoid looks like?" :) I would like to know about this :D.. I will try to make the question clearer..

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I did not doubt when you said the question is confusing.. :) I do think it is slightly unclear.. I will make it clearer..

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I could not make it any better than "what an arbitrary (good enough) Lie groupoid looks like?"... Do you have any "comment" for a special case or variant of this question? As it is, it looks open ended... :(

Comment: @DavidRoberts I could not make it any better than "what an arbitrary (good enough) Lie groupoid looks like?"... Do you have any "comment" for a special case or variant of this question? As it is, it looks open ended... :(

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik yes, it's open ended. Maybe the best you can ask for is for more functors that produce Lie groupoids from other data that end up being not Morita equivalent to the ones on the list. As it is, your list has reasonable overlap (1. and 2. are both special cases of 3., for example; and there's a relation between 4. and 5., since a submersion defines a foliation of its domain, 6. and 7. are special cases, as I mentioned, of the groupoid arising from a rather general fibre bundle...)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes. I think the same. I will leave it as it is and edit if I can get some interesting special case as a question.